# Getting abs_attrs.xml error while working with ActionBarSherlock and appcompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

i want to integrate ActionBarSherlock and appcompat_v7 then import these to my project. But i faced some problems. Here they are:

```
C:\Users\win7\workspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__attrs.xml:4: error: Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined   
C:\Users\win7\workspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__attrs.xml:5: error: Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
C:\Users\win7\workspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__attrs.xml:6: error: Attribute "background" has already been defined
C:\Users\win7\workspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__attrs.xml:7: error: Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
```

And so on... 
I have 104 errors and 66 warnings.

I tried to add new library, jar then removed them but didn't work.

Also i changed directory of appcompat again and again, but nothing worked.

What should i do ?

Comment: Solved this problem by right clicking library of my project(android-support-v7-appcompat) then Properties->Android tab on left side->  and changed Project Build Target from API 19 to API 21 as my fundamental project owns API 21. The trick is that they must have same Project Target.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this can be done by removing AppCompat from your dependencies.
In Xamarin Studio this can be done in the solution view: Go References/"From Packages" -> Select the AppCompat package, and delete it.